# Flood fill adjacent values of boundary

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an algorithm where I can get the adjacent values of flood fill. Assuming I have the following 2d array:

[image]

I need to be able to add the values in yellow, which are the boundary of the flood fill. So far I managed to do a flood fill, which is not really the scope of my exercise, but a starting point. Any ideas how I can get the boundary values. Here is the code I have so far?

```
    // Java program to implement flood fill algorithm
class GFG
{

// Dimensions of paint screen
static int M = 8;
static int N = 8;

// A recursive function to replace previous color 'prevC' at '(x, y)'
// and all surrounding pixels of (x, y) with new color 'newC' and
static void floodFillUtil(int screen[][], int x, int y,
                                    int prevC, int newC)
{
    // Base cases
    if (x < 0 || x >= M || y < 0 || y >= N)
        return;
            if (screen[x][y] != prevC){
        return;
    }
    // Replace the color at (x, y)
    screen[x][y] = newC;

    // Recur for north, east, south and west
    floodFillUtil(screen, x+1, y, prevC, newC);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x-1, y, prevC, newC);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x, y+1, prevC, newC);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x, y-1, prevC, newC);
    
}

// It mainly finds the previous color on (x, y) and
// calls floodFillUtil()
static void floodFill(int screen[][], int x, int y, int newC)
{
    int prevC = screen[x][y];
    if(prevC==newC) return;
    floodFillUtil(screen, x, y, prevC, newC);
}

// Driver code
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int screen[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                    {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                    {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0},
                    {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1},
                    };
    int x = 4, y = 4, newC = 3;
    floodFill(screen, x, y, newC);

    System.out.println("Updated screen after call to floodFill: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        System.out.print(screen[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void floodFill(int screen[][], int x, int y, int newC) {
    int rows = screen.length, cols = screen[0].length;
    int prevC = screen[x][y];
    if (prevC == newC) return;
    new Object() {
        Set<Point> visited = new HashSet<>();
        void fill(int x, int y) {
            if (x < 0 || x >= rows || y < 0 || y >= cols) return;
            Point visit = new Point(x, y);
            if (visited.contains(visit)) return;
            visited.add(visit);
            if (screen[x][y] == prevC) {
                for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
                        fill(x + i, y + j);
            } else
                screen[x][y] = newC;
        }
    }.fill(x, y);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int screen[][] = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1},
    };

    int x = 4, y = 4, newC = 3;
    floodFill(screen, x, y, newC);

    System.out.println("Updated screen after call to floodFill: ");
    for (int[] row : screen)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

output:

```
Updated screen after call to floodFill: 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0]
[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks